# Angular JS interceptors

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set up an interceptor to catch 403 responses.

In my config function I have added this to test things out

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
        return {
            request: function(config) {
                console.log('test');
            },
            responce: function(responce) {
                console.log(responce);
                if(responce.status === 403) {
                    console.log('403')
                }
                return responce || $q.when(responce);
            },
            responceError: function(rejection) {
                console.log(rejection);
                if(rejection.status === 403) {
                    console.log('403', rejection);
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        }
    });
```

When I reload the page I get the following output to console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined 
test
```

In an infinite loop that crashes the browser tab

If I remove the request method from the object then I never get anything output to console

I am using Angular version: 1.2.22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that your `request` callback is not returning the `config` parameter, check the [`$http` interceptors documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors):

> **request:** interceptors get called with a http config object. The
>   function is free to modify the config object or create a new one. The
>   function needs to **return the config object directly, or a promise**
>   **containing the config or a new config object**.

The second problem is you are spelling response incorrectly, simply change `responce` and `responceError` to `response` and `responseError` respectively.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/99DE9yA2UrCwcZIbsf3K?p=preview)**

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            console.log('test');
            return config;
        },
        response: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if(response.status === 403) {
                console.log('403')
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function(rejection) {
            console.log(rejection);
            if(rejection.status === 403) {
                console.log('403', rejection);
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Response is spelled with an s, not with a c.